# How to move ImageButtons

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am working on an application for Android in Eclipse, but I have some problems with the look of the menu. I have several buttons that people can click and play sounds with them. The problem is that I don't know how to start a new line and go on with more buttons.

I'll post two images. I think the image title will tell you everything.

**1st:**

[image: http://postimg.org/image/gv54y5dcb/]

---

**2nd:**

[image: http://postimg.org/image/l1exyea09/]

---

The 2nd image is made with PhotoShop.

XML:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="665dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/aatrox_imgbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/aatrox" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ahri_imgbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ahri" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/akali_imgbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/akali" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/alistar_imgbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/alistar" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/amumu_imgbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/amumu" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/anivia_imgbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/anivia" />



            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/annie_imgbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/annie" />




        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back_champions"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:text="@string/back" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried moving the image buttons with the mouse but no success.

Comment: You have to use GridView and inflate the Xml layout which should have only one Image button and this button will increase according to your image count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need grid view. check out sample 
[grid view sample](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/)